# OMAP 4430 Usage of Linux with DSP

Tags: linux, pandaboard, omap

I am wondering if I can use DSP core in OMAP4430 PandaBoard-ES with code running on Linux OS to speed up some processes? I just want to make some processes inside my code via DSP core and the rest via CPU. Along with my search, I cannot find any good information about it. Is there any tutorial that you can propose? If this process is possible, standard multi-threading techniques is enough to make them run in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try [distributed codec engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Codec_Engine) ([sources at github](https://github.com/robclark/libdce)). As an example - [github again](https://github.com/robclark/omapdrmtest).

Standard threading model can be used in the following way - one thread on *ARM* is working while second thread at *ARM* is waiting for completion of *DSP* job and in the end it reads data from DSP (for example a blocking process call mentioned [here](https://github.com/robclark/libdce/blob/master/packages/codec_engine/ti/sdo/ce/video3/viddec3.h#L245) in video decoding api).